# .NET: Mock a service I do not control

Tags: c#, .net, service, mocking

How can I mock a service that I do not have control of (an external companies service to which I have access but do not want to hit when running my unit tests).

I am writing my consumer in C# .NET 4.6. My intended aim is to be able to test the inner workings of my consumer (and then the library code that consumes that) without actually hitting the remote service. Unfortunately the remote service is rather complicated and has a large number of calls and types of its own.

Any assistance or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: After an immediate down vote with no comment; please let me add: I have goggled this but unfortunately did not get answers that helped me. Perhaps just poor search terms.

Edit 2: The remote service is asmx. My consumer is a .net 4.6 library that will act as the control library for any consuming user interface (be it wpf, winform, mvc, etc).

Comment: Create a proxy and and fake version. Run tests against the fake.

Comment: Google returns tons of results when I search for "Mock web service C#" so that's a poor excuse.If you provide more details and perhaps a code sample,  we'll be able to help you further.

Comment: @hbulens not sure how a code sample would help when I am asking for advice/pointers towards a solution (not to be given one, but to be aided in discovering one). My searches came up with examples that required me to have access to code from the service.

Comment: You can start by telling us which technology you are working with. Is it asmx, wcf, rest,... we can't tell by your question. Then again, looking for "mocking external web service C#" on google returns heaps of good articles on the web and in particular this site. Do your research.

Comment: To mock a service can be done by creating your own server and then changing the client to connect to your service rather then the remote.  But there is no way of simplifying the complexity of mocking all the commands and responses.  Instead you may just want to perform a syntax check of the commands and return a standard response to the commands rather than a real response.  The standard response could just be a lookup table.

Comment: @hbulens info added to the question. Yes I looked as some of those responses before asking the question. The idea of creating an interface for a service with 100+ methods was painful; so I thought I would ask SO for advice. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

You can abstract the external service functionality into an interface (IExternalService), and then create another implementation for it (besides the original one), a mock one: MockExternalService. This one could be as simple as just return some dummy data, or can also have some logic inside (return different response depending on a certain input in method params, for example).

You then need to wire all this up so that through a certain mechanism (custom header/web.config setting/db setting, for example) your consumer can swap between the 2 different service implementations (this somewhat implies that you're using Dependency Injection).

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the imported Service Reference class, choose "Extract Interface" and you have the beginnings of your mock. Change all your existing code that references the concrete service reference class to referencing the new interface, then where you create a new instance of the concrete class, replace that code with a factory using your favourite IOC framework (or just write the factory yourself).

Then create a "TestServiceEndpoint" class implementing the extracted interface and start writing your mock responses.

Alternatively use the Visual Studio Fakes capability to create a Fake implementation and write tests with that. This is only really suitable for a unit test framework environment though, so if you are trying to stub out the endpoint so you can test the rest of your application, the first approach is the best.